# Removing which subset of X(connected metric space) will guarantee the lose of X's connectivity?

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $(X,d)$ be an arbitrary connected metric space with $A \subset X$. What property of $A$ will ensure that $X\setminus A$ is disconnected?

Is there any interesting characterization of such $A$?

---

My thoughts:

1. $A$ being dense doesn't work. Counterexample: $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{Q}^2.$
2. $A$ being closed doesn't work. Counterexample: $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus B[0,1].$
3. I think if I consider a Normed Linear Space $X$, with $A$ being a hyperplane of $X$, then $X \setminus A$ is disconnected. But I am not sure if this is true.

Comment: $A$ being $X$ minus $2$ points?

Comment: This works. Is there any interesting characterization of such an $A$?

Comment: Here is a paper to clear your doubts about #3. http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/hyperplaneconnd.pdf

Comment: 3. works for real spaces. A hyperplane $A$ is of codimension $1$, so choose a direct complement $B = \mathrm{span}\{b\}$. For any vector $x\in X$ there is a unique vector $a\in A$ and a unique scalar $\lambda_x\in\mathbb R$ such that $x = a + \lambda_x b$. Finally, $X\setminus A = \{ x\in X\mid \lambda_x > 0 \} \cup \{ x\in X\mid \lambda_x < 0 \}$ is nontrivial partition into open disjoint subsets. Of course, you need functional $x\mapsto \lambda_x$ to be bounded. However, if it were unbounded, $A$ should be dense in $X$, and to be honest, I'm not sure if that counts as a hyperplane or not.